# RSS feed for localized Stack Overflow sites uses favicon from English Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, feed, localization, favicon, russian-stackoverflow

RSS feed page for localized SO sites uses favicon from enSO. E.g. ruSO uses favicons with blue color:

- [main site](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/):

  > [image: main]
- [meta site](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/):

  > [image: meta]

But if you open RSS feed from these sites you'll see icons used in enSO:

- for [feed from main ruSO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/feeds) used favicon as for main enSO:

  > [image: enSO]
- for [feed from meta ruSO](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds) used favicon as for meta enSO:

  > [image: enSO]

Tested on Firefox and Chrome browsers for Windows.

I think favicon for feeds on localized sites should be same as for sites itself.

Comment: There is no excplicit favicon being served there so it takes the default http://ru.stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico and that serves this [one](http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico) or in plaintext: `http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico`